# Reverse for 'mobile' not found. 'mobile' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, html, django

urls.py

from django.urls import path
from app import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [

```
path('',views.ProductView.as_view(),name="home"),
path('product-detail/<int:pk>', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product-detail'),
path('cart/', views.add_to_cart, name='add-to-cart'),
path('buy/', views.buy_now, name='buy-now'),
path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
path('address/', views.address, name='address'),
path('orders/', views.orders, name='orders'),
path('changepassword/', views.change_password, name='changepassword'),
path('mobile/<slug:data>', views.mobile, name='mobiledata'),
path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
path('registration/', views.customerregistration, name='customerregistration'),
path('checkout/', views.checkout, name='checkout'),
```

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: Likely the view should be `mobiledata`, not `mobile`.

Comment: dumping a file is however *not* a question. You should share the full traceback together with relevant model(s), view(s), url(s), template(s), etc.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have a URL named 'mobile' you have a URL named 'mobiledata'.

you can change your URL name to 'mobile' or change it to 'mobiledata' wherever you are reversing.

Comment: still have issue,     Reverse for 'mobiledata' not found.

Comment: u need to show your views template and the structure